# Installing mcrypt with PHP on mac

Tags: php, mcrypt

I am trying to install the mcrypt extension for PHP on my mac.

I used the homebrew command to install it

```
 brew install php53-mcrypt
```

This gives me a message saying that it is already installed: `php53-mcrypt-5.3.26 already installed`

However, when I run the command `php -m`, I do not see mcrypt in the list (I have restarted the terminal).

**Edit 1:** Adding mcrypt section of php.ini.default

In the php.ini.default file, this is section I have regarding mcrypt

```
[mcrypt]
; For more information about mcrypt settings see http://php.net/mcrypt-module-open

; Directory where to load mcrypt algorithms
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
;mcrypt.algorithms_dir=

; Directory where to load mcrypt modes
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
;mcrypt.modes_dir=
```

Comment: Find out what `php.ini` file is in use `php -i` (and any other config files) and make sure the extension is enabled

Comment: what am i looking for? it outputs a lot of data

Comment: Try `php -i | grep '\.ini'`. Paste the results into your question

Comment: This is what I got 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini

Comment: Is the extension enabled in `/etc/php.ini`? You might also want to check via a browser using a `<?php phpinfo() ?>` file. Sometimes, the CLI and web module use different `php.ini` files

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer, please have a look at it. Hope that would be helpful.

Comment: @Phil, I tried phpinfo() and it gave me another path to a php.ini file. This one is in the MAMP directory that I am using. I opened this file and it does have `extension=mcrypt.so` in the file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fisrt, find out where is the `php.ini`:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Then you will see something like these:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/php/etc
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php54/php.ini
```

Open the Configuration File:

```
vim /usr/local/etc/php54/php.ini
```

search this file and check if you have something like this:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

copy `mcrypt.so` to `extension_dir` which is indicated also in php.ini.

or set `mcrypt.modes_dir`

```
mcrypt.modes_dir=/usr/lib/libmcrypt.so
```

Comment: i have this line `; extension_dir = "ext"` so, do i write `extension = mcrypt.so` below that ?

Comment: yes, you can set `extension_dir=/usr/local/php/lib/`, then copy `mcrypt.so` to `extension_dir`.

Comment: Yes, it finally worked. I had to write the full path of the mcrypt.so. `extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php53-mcrypt/5.3.26/mcrypt.so"`

Answer (score 1):

Updated guide as of Mac Mavericks:

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-development-server/